# How to connect to self-hosted Gitlab from gitlab-runner using Docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using a Dockerized Gitlab setup in a private network.

My Gitlab server is at 172.16.X.Y where X and Y are valid IP address components on my network. I am using the `docker-compose.yml` setup pfor this Dockerized Gitlab:

https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab

- The only thing I have changed is the `GITLAB_HOST` parameter, which I set to 172.16.X.Y.
- From my computer, I can access Gitlab web interface on 172.16.X.Y:10080, and I can clone repositories with SSH using a key and with http using a token.
- 172.16.X.Y is running RHEL 7
- I installed gitlab-runner on 176.16.X.Y. When trying to use CI using the Docker executor, I get the following issue:

`fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@172.16.X.Y:10080/stephen.barr/test-docker-ci.git/': Failed to connect to 172.16.X.Y port 10080: Host is unreachable
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`

I can clone this repo when I login as `gitlab-runner` on 172.16.X.Y. How can I get gitlab runner to see the git server?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Had the same problem today. Solved it with a reboot of the server running gitlab and gitlab-runner. While this solved the problem for me that does not mean that this is a final solution for this problem.

Comment: Same issue. Server reboot was not the answer :-(